# Is there an easy way to add TMX Object Layer to a Scene in Andengine?

Tags: andengine

I have a TMX file with a MAP layer and Object layer (called decorations, with property type = "decorations"). Is there an easy way to add the whole layer to the scene with all objects? Or do I have to iterate through objects and add them one by one?

Comment: I can't change the layer to Map Layer, because the decorations are placed with pixel precision.

Comment: I am going through the AndEngine TMX sources and it looks like it doesn't count with an object being an actual tile from some tileset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the TMX extension code, I am pretty sure there is no easy way. The extension doesn't implement objects layers as attachable to the scene, nor it read all information from the TMX file in the current version.